# How can I style a nested radio input, or how can i make react control sibling inputs and labels?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a conundrum,

I am making controlled radio buttons in react and styling them to look like regular buttons, but...

I don't know how to make them completely controlled when having the label and input as siblings, which is what the custom styling technique I am using requires, or...

I don't know how to style the buttons in a completely custom way while making them completely controlled...

So I don't how it's done, but I need to make these buttons completely custom and completely controlled...dunno how to achieve this using either react and/or css/css-in-js.

If you are wondering, I do indeed need the radio buttons completely controlled, because if they are not then component encapsulation breaks and I am re-using this component on the same page multiple times. If I have `id`'s and `class`'s and `for`'s in the attributes then each instance ends up messing with another instance, which makes the component unusable in my app.

Here is the code for sibling radio buttons:

```js
<NoteInput
  type="radio"
  name="notes"
  value="c"
  id="c"
  label="c"
  scale={scale}
  checked={radioValue === `c`}
  onChange={{handleRadioChange}
/>
<NoteLabel
  scale={scale}
  htmlFor="c"
>
  {
    C
  }
</NoteLabel>
```

and here would be the code for the nested radio button:

```js
<NoteLabel>
  <NoteInput
    type="radio"
    value={'c'}
    checked={radioValue === 'c'}
    onChange={handleRadioChange}
  />
  C
</NoteLabel>
```

the second option is less code as well, which is nice...

Now here is the css for the first option, which works, but is not completely controlled:

```js
const NoteLabel = styled(motion.label)`
  ${Label}
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  ${props =>
    props.scale === 'major' ? css`${MajorButton}` :
    props.scale === 'minor' ? css`${MinorButton}` :
    css`${GreyButton}`
  }
`

const NoteInput = styled.input`
  display: none;
  &:checked + ${NoteLabel} {
    background: ${props =>
      props.scale === 'major' ? css`hsla(${Major}, 1)` :
      props.scale === 'minor' ? css`hsla(${Minor}, 1)` :
      css`${GreyButton}`
    };
  }
`
```

The colors and basic label styles are defined in `css` blocks and work properly, but the biggest thing here is the use of the sibling selector ( + ), which is what makes the jsx of the first option work. Nesting the input inside the label breaks this approach, but I do not know how to achieve the same effect without using the sibling selector. There is not parent selector in css, so I cannot select the parent of the input, which would make this technique work for nested inputs, I do believe, tho not sure...

...and here is what the radio buttons look like with this styling:

[image: Custom styled rows of radio buttons to convey which scale and white note are currently selected.]

Notice that the first row of buttons are a set of mutually exclusive buttons that allow the user to select a musical scale type, and the second row of mutually exclusive buttons are a set of buttons that allow the user to select a root for the scale, at which point in time the notes for that scale appear on the keyboard.

So ultimately, I want the look of a regular button (rounded rectangle with label inside), but the behavior of a radio button, and I want for them to be completely controlled by react (no `for` or `id`, etc...) so as to not break encapsulation, which would make the component essentially useless to me.

And I am totally not opposed to using regular `<button>`'s either, so long as I can re-create the same behavior as radio buttons offer, which is that only one button of a group of buttons can be selected at the same time and stays selected until another choice is made.

If anything is unclear pleas let me know and I will update the question with any necessary changes...

Thank you :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "not completely controlled"? Input elements/components are either **controlled** or **uncontrolled**, there's no in-between. Could you share your entire component code so it's clearer what your state implementation is and what/why it may not be working as you expect?

Comment: hmmmm...what I'm referring to is that react does not control the generation of `id`'s for each input, and an id is a requirement of inputs with sibling labels...so react is controlling the `checked`, `onChange` and `value` props, but not the `id`...the issue is that since the id is not under reacts control, then i end up with id's being reused on every instance of a component, therefore making them interact in bad ways and breaking the functionality of the component...if this is not the normal definition of controlled, my apologies, but it would be nice if react controlled id's as well...

Comment: OFC react doesn't control `id`'s, those are for you to specify, and have nothing to do with controlled/uncontrolled inputs. React has a pretty specific definition of ["controlled"](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). How are you creating/using `id`'s now? What is breaking? Please be more specific. Could you share your entire component code so it's clearer what your state implementation/management is and what/why it may not be working as you expect?

Comment: ok, so i would love for react to encapsulate and/or generate id's for each instance of a component, as I am just manually adding id's to the component for each radio button, and when I add two or more instances of the component to the same page if I click on buttons in one instance it directly affects buttons in another instance, because the id's are global and shared by every instance of the same component. Let me see if I can remove some code from the component and post it, as it's currently almost 1,000 lines right now...

Comment: if I use the radio button code fro mthe second example then this problem goes away, as no id's are needed and no htmlFor to connect the label to the button, so the instances of the component do not affect each other, but I can't figure out how to style the radio buttons in the same fashion with this approach, which is where I'm stuck...

Comment: Well, I have a codesandox that I think solves this, but to me it's still unclear whether or not you're using controlled or uncontrolled form elements, and which of the three "groups of buttons" you're actually referring to. Awaiting your sharing of a minimal, complete, and reproducible code snippet.